# Push a string to an empty Array without it becoming a sub array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sub-array

I have a `sad array` which consists of a string.

`var sadArray = ["I am a happy sentence."];`

I would like to take this sentence out of the `sad array` (because its not a sad sentence :) ) and move it into the `happy array`

`var happyArray = [];`

This is the way I am trying to go about this

`happyArray.push(sadArray);`

However, the result of this is that the whole `sadArray` not just the sentence inside it, gets pushed to the `happyArray` resulting in a 2d array

`console.log(happyArray); //returns [ [ "I am a happy sentence." ] ]`

How can i achieve this outcome?:

`console.log(sadArray); //returns empty array because i removed the happy sentence from it`

`console.log(happyArray); //returns ["I am a happy sentence."]`

Comment: Show us how you push

Comment: please add the part where the pushing happens.

Comment: `var myArray = ["Welcome to the World"];` or `var myArray = []; myArray.push("Welcome to the World");`

Comment: what happens to the people?

Comment: `var myArray = []; myArray.push("YOUR STRING");`

Comment: APOLOGIES, UPDATED QUESTION TO BE CLEARER AND WITH MORE CODE

Comment: @samibirnbaum did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push works perfectly fine. Check the code, if you push the array again into another array then you will get `[[welcome to the world people]]` like in `anotherArray`. Otherwise, the first push to `myArray` simply works fine.

```js
var myString = "welcome to the world people";
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(myString);
console.log(myArray);

var anotherArray = [];
anotherArray.push(myArray);
console.log(anotherArray);
```